# Undefined Offset :1 and 2

Tags: php, sql, undefined, offset, explode

I am using explode function to insert a text pipe delimited file in sql table .

The error is :

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 
Both on line 34
```

ie.

```
 $list=explode("|",$line);
 $sql="INSERT INTO tb (tb1,tb2,tb3) VALUES('$list[0]','$list[1]','$list[2]')";
```

Please help.

```
  while (!feof($handler)) // Loop til end of file.
  {
       $line= fgets($handler);     // Read a line
       $list=explode("|",$line);
       $sql="INSERT INTO tb (tb1,tb2,tb3) VALUES('$list[0]','$list[1]','$list[2]')";
       $result= mysql_query($sql,$conn);             
  }
```

Comment: did you `print_r($list)` to confirm there is content? undefined offset means that there is no `$list[1]` and `$list[2]`

Comment: Yes you are right ! There are no $list[1] and $list[2].
But then how to insert the exploded $line into sql databse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not care about values you could do this

```
$list=explode("|", $line) + array('', '', '');
```

You array would be always has 3 elements.